# How to get a composer label by ID with Python in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I have a script that was working, where I was able to grab a composer label by its ID and then update its text by doing the following:

```
labelTitle = myComposition.getComposerItemById('pageTitle')
labelTitle.setText('New Title')
```

But after updating to the latest version of QGIS, it looks like labelTitle is coming back as a QgsComposerItem type instead of QgsComposerLabel, so it is throwing the error `'QgsComposerItem' object has no attribute 'setText'`

Is there a way to cast it as a label, or am I missing something? Or is there an entirely better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you generate your title from a field in the map or are you using the atlas function?. If using a field in a vector file you could do something like `This is the [%"field_name"%]` where field name would hold your string

Comment: @LaughU Yeah I actually just figured this out and was about to update my post. I'm generating it from a field and was doing it programmatically in the script so that I could change the size based on the length of the title, but I ended up just using a conditional in the label expression. I'm still curious how to target a composer label with Python though!

Comment: could you add which QGIS version you used and which you are using now?

Comment: @LaughU I'm on 2.18.7 running on a Mac, previously I want to say it was 2.18.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another workaround suggested by Nyall Dawson (cast) :

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayoutItemPicture
import sip
myLayout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('test')
myLayoutPicture = sip.cast(myLayout.itemById("picture"), QgsLayoutItemPicture)
myLayoutPicture.setPicturePath("path to an image")
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem for me, solved with this:

```
    [...]
    item = myComposition.getComposerItemById("id_field")
    item = self.bugWAGetComposerLabel(item)
    item.setText("my value")
    [...]


def bugWAGetComposerLabel(self, item):
    if not item.__class__ == QgsComposerLabel:
        if item.type() == QgsComposerItem.ComposerLabel:
            item.__class__ = QgsComposerLabel
    return item
```

Comment: Same problem here (QGIS 2.99), but with this code I get an error :
`'QgsComposerLabel' object has no attribute 'setText'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround I found with the help of QGIS Developer list :

```
@staticmethod
def getCompositionItem(composition, itemId, itemClass):
    item = None
    for item in composition.items():
        if isinstance(item, itemClass):
            if item.id() == itemId:
                return item
```

Using this custom function instead of getComposerItemById I can get composition items with their actual subclass.