# QGIS an PDF templates: getComposerItemById is changed with the QGis version?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, pdf

In a QGis python plugin i have this code to fill in the fields of a PDF template (.qpt):

```
    myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
    myFile = path + "template.qpt"
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

    item = myComposition.getComposerItemById("id_field")
    item.setText("my value")
```

working with QGis 2.18.7 **item** is a **qgis._core.QgsComposerLabel** and the method setText() is correct.

working with QGis 2.18.13 **item** is a **qgis._core.QgsComposerItem** and the method setText() not exist.

Is getComposerItemById changed with the QGIS version?

Comment: same problem not yet solved here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241213/how-to-get-a-composer-label-by-id-with-python-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

whit this code:

```
    [...]
    item = myComposition.getComposerItemById("id_field")
    item = self.bugWAGetComposerLabel(item)
    item.setText("my value")
    [...]


def bugWAGetComposerLabel(self, item):
    if not item.__class__ == QgsComposerLabel:
        if item.type() == QgsComposerItem.ComposerLabel:
            item.__class__ = QgsComposerLabel
    return item
```