# Do the elements in Print Composer have any identifiers in QGIS 2.18.14?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In QGIS 2:18:14, it is possible to refer to elements in the Print Composer?

How do I name and identify an element in another element?

E.g., on a label, call the contents of another label and use its content to do some calculations?

Let say: in a label, **Label 1 and Label 2**,  or **Label 1 + Label 2**, ...

[image]

Comment: For the calculation...do you mean something like "Label 3 = (concatenate) Label1+Label2". I think something like this is possible using the Atlas controls...but other than that, the labels don't have attributes which can be worked with in this way

Comment: This is possible with Python: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241213/how-to-get-a-composer-label-by-id-with-python-in-qgis